# Google App and Google Play Services force close - SecurityException

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, google-play-services, force-close, google-search

My friend's Samsung Galaxy S phone (with CM11) has been recently having an issue, where Google Play Services has been randomly crashing with this message in the logcat:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10103 or current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
```

The same thing happens to the Google App upon trying to perform a search in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the GApps flashed onto the phone after flashing the ROM is indeed supported on that ROM.
If you are using the package provided by Cyanogen then please download Delta GApps below. The package provided by Cyanogen has some bugs.

[GApps for all KitKat+ CMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/app-minimal-gapps-gapps-lp-20150107-1-t2997368)

1) Download the base package for KitKat

2) Download standard Addons for KitKat

3) Download any other addons for KitKat you may want.

4) Transfer files onto your device.

5) Boot into your custom recovery.

6) Wipe Cache, Dalvik Cache.

7) Install/Flash the zips/packages.

8) Boot into CM11.

9) Try opening them now. If you're unable to open Clear Data of all the Google Apps and try again.